# SQL: Invalid column name error

Tags: sql-server

If I run the select statement alone for both dates it returns the correct date but when it's included in the code it doesn't. I need some assistance please.

```
SELECT r.[Holding Co], 
       r.[Reference Order No], 
       r.Reg, 
       r.SL, 
       r.[Order Date],  
    CASE WHEN [Type]<>'Recovery' 
      AND [Status]<>'Inter' 
      AND [Status]<>'Cancelled' 
      AND [Order Date]<[Date Order] 
      AND [CICD Actual] IS NULL 
      OR [CICD Actual]>[Date Outstanding] 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 End AS [Outstanding], 
    --CASE WHEN /* many more calculated fields and cases redacted for brevity ... */                                          
      Month([Date Outstanding]) AS [Month], 
      Year([Date Outstanding]) AS [Year],  
      CAST(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-01') as Date) AS [Date Order],
      DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) AS [Date Outstanding]    

FROM unisat.Register AS r;
```

> Error:  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Invalid column name 'Date
>   Order'. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Invalid column name 'Date
>   Outstanding'

Comment: When you say you ran the select statement for both dates do you mean you used `SELECT [Order Date], [Date Order] FROM...` or could you show us what you did?

Comment: Your error clearly states that there is some issue with column names, In the first place take a look at them.

Comment: Thank You Jonathan,  Select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) This is suppose to be my [Date Outstanding] , and Select cast(format(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-01') as Date) is [Date Order]

Comment: Only one `CASE` necessary to understand the question, here.

Answer (score 1):

The [Date Outstanding] is introduced in the SELECT list, and you cannot use it in the same select list as a basis for something else.

I'd suggest to refactor the calculation for this (and the [Date Order] as well) into a CTE, and then you could use it in the outer select, something like this:

```
;with x as (
    SELECT r.[Holding Co], 
           r.[Reference Order No], 
           r.Reg, 
           r.SL, 
           r.[Order Date], 
           r.[Type] ,
           r.[Status],
           r.[CICD Actual],
          CAST(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-01') as Date) AS [Date Order],
          DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) AS [Date Outstanding]    
    FROM unisat.Register AS r
)
SELECT x.[Holding Co], 
    x.[Reference Order No], 
    x.Reg, 
    x.SL, 
    x.[Order Date], 
    CASE WHEN x.[Type]<>'Recovery' 
        AND x.[Status]<>'Inter' 
        AND x.[Status]<>'Cancelled' 
        AND x.[Order Date]<x.[Date Order] 
        AND x.[CICD Actual] IS NULL 
        OR x.[CICD Actual]>x.[Date Outstanding] 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 End AS [Outstanding], 
    CASE WHEN /* many more calculated fields and cases redacted for brevity ... */                                          
    Month(x.[Date Outstanding]) AS [Month], 
    Year(x.[Date Outstanding]) AS [Year],
    x.[Date Order],
    x.[Date Outstanding]  
from x;
```